# при вызове get блокируется основной поток

Tags: android

```
public class JsonServer extends AsyncTask<Void,Void,JSONObject> {
    private Context context;
    private ProgressDialog progressDialog;
    private String str;

    public JsonServer(Context context,String str){
        this.context=context;
        this.str=str;
    }

    @Override
    protected void onPreExecute() {
        super.onPreExecute();
        progressDialog=new ProgressDialog(context);
        progressDialog.setTitle("Получение данных");
        progressDialog.show();
    }

    @Override
    protected JSONObject doInBackground(Void... params) {
        try {
            Thread.sleep(2500);
        } catch (InterruptedException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
        return null;
    }

    @Override
    protected void onPostExecute(JSONObject jsonObject) {
        super.onPostExecute(jsonObject);
        progressDialog.dismiss();
    }
}
```

Как вызвать `get` у `AsyncTask`, чтобы `ProgressDialog` работал?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

В общем, как-то так:

```
final JsonServer jsonServer=new JsonServer(getActivity(),"http://i/?group_id=15704");
        jsonServer.execute();

        new Thread(new Runnable() {
            @Override
            public void run() {
                try {
                    jsonServer.get();
                    Log.e("asd","DA");
                } catch (InterruptedException e) {
                    e.printStackTrace();
                } catch (ExecutionException e) {
                    e.printStackTrace();
                }
            }
        }).start();
```

Конечно, это может быть плохим кодом. Если у кого-то есть более правильный код, напишите, пожалуйста.

Comment: а какая цель вообще? использование AsyncTask накладывает много ограничений, если повернуть экран, asycktask в лучшем случае вернет данные в новую активити, в худшем потеряются данные. Есть прекрасная библиотека robospice, которая позволяет убрать все эти подводные камни, и писать качественные restfull приложения

Comment: @DenisZinkovskiy, Цель простая. Вот допустим в VK. Когда сдвигаешь сверху вниз. то идут линии и обновляется данные в этом окне.
Так как я такое делать не могу пока. 

Вообщем надо чтобы запустился ProgressDialog он крутился, пока даннные из сервера не будут приняты, и после этого ProgressDialog выключится. 

Обычное Окно загрузки.Как в играх и т.д.

Comment: это очень легко сделать, в интернете есть много туториалов и библиотек реализовывающих эту фичу, вот одна подробная [статья](https://www.bignerdranch.com/blog/implementing-swipe-to-refresh/)